# Как в PyCharm запустить программу в системной консоли?

Tags: pycharm

Внезапно оказалось, что PyCharm Community под Windows [плохо работает с \r и ломает прогресс-бары](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/307) (в линуксах всё хорошо). (Галочка «Emulate terminal in output console» не помогает: поведение становится немного лучше, но всё равно глючное.) Но работать с \r всё же хочется. Раз в PyCharm эту проблему [не исправляют уже много лет](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-86669), то само собой напрашивается запуск программы в родной системной консоли, в которой \r работает как положено.

Как настроить параметры запуска так, чтобы программа программа запускалась в системной консоли? В первую очередь интересует Windows (ибо проблема на ней), но что-нибудь кросс-платформенное будет тоже хорошо.

Гугл знает про [какую-то галочку «Use external console»](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/user_images/mXMflrPBkODqpE4-XTC0jQ.png), но это, похоже, то ли только в IDEA, то ли не для питона, то ли только в Pro версии, то ли выпилили — но в общем у себя я такой галочки не вижу.

Comment: Наверное, можно по хитрому через `External tools` вызывать

Answer (score 1):

Запустить код в консоли Python под PyCharm Community можно парой предусмотренных способов:

1. Shift+Alt+E по выбранному коду. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/loading-code-from-editor-into-console.html
2. Run > Edit Configurations и выбрать Show command line afterwards [(подробнее)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42562734/how-to-run-a-file-in-ipython-console-as-default-instead-of-terminal/43492098) Но как я понял, при использовании данного способа, придется для каждого нового проекта делать это. Ибо конфигурация именно проекта. (может быть кто поправит)

Но как открыть отдельную от IDE python консоль не знаю =)

Comment: Первый способ не запускает системную консоль, во втором у меня отсутствует Show command line afterwards (но что-то я подозреваю, что он тоже системную не запустит)